# How can I access JSF ResourceBundle from Spring Webflow expression?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-webflow, resourcebundle

I'm trying to come up with a clean way of having a String resource bundle for my application, that contains my JSF labels etc and my messages and errors.

What I have is a 'Create Element' page that flows on save to a validate function.

```
    <transition on="save" to="validateElementCreate" validate="false" > 
        <evaluate expression="newElement.validate(messageContext)" /> 
    </transition>
```

My element validate function adds messages to the context it's provided but they are hard coded. So I want to pass a resource bundle in to the function with it.

My resource bundle is named "element_maintenance_msgs" so I tried to do this:

```
    <transition on="save" to="validateElementCreate" validate="false" > 
        <evaluate expression="newElement.validate(messageContext, 
                                                  element_maintenance_msgs)" /> 
    </transition>
```

which doesn't work becasue the resource bundle configured in faces-config.xml, isn't visible to the webflow.

What are my options for providing portability of the bundle?

Comment: I know nothing about Faces, and I know this is somewhat kludgey, but could you perhaps have Spring double-load the same resource bundle that Faces is loading?

Comment: I couldn't do that because JSF will load the resource for a language based on the browser preferences so I need the actual one it's using. I've managed it though.

Comment: FWIW, Spring has interceptors which also select the correct locale based on the browser preferences.

Comment: What is the requirement to have the JSF resource bundle? We run a Spring Webflow + JSF application and we have no problems with a Spring MessageSource. It is accessible from Spring, WebFlow flows, and JSF EL. If this seems like it might be the solution you need I can share the details.